# Getting black and white intensity values from a histogram

Tags: image-processing, opencv, histogram

I am trying to get black and white histogram data from a  color image. However the current setup I have with my histogram only shows me color data I'm sure that it's something that I have to modify in my current math setup.

```
// Current setup on how to render histogram data to the screen with hist being the calculated histogram
histimg = Mat::zeros(200, 320, CV_8UC3)
int binW = histimg.cols / 16;
Mat buf(1, 16, CV_8UC3);
for( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
{
    buf.at<Vec3b>(i) = Vec3b(saturate_cast<uchar>(i*180./16), 255, 255);
}
cvtColor(buf, buf, CV_HSV2BGR);

for( int i = 0; i < 16; i++ )
{
    int val = saturate_cast<int>(hist.at<float>(i)*histimg.rows/255);
    rectangle( histimg, Point(i*binW,histimg.rows),
        Point((i+1)*binW,histimg.rows - val),
        Scalar(buf.at<Vec3b>(i)), -1, 8 );
}
```

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by _I am trying to get black and white histogram data from a color image._ Do you mean you want a histogram of the grayscale intensities of a color image? Or are you trying to draw a histogram in black and white? Also, "black and white" in computer vision is different than in television. On TV it means various shades of gray. In our world it is one of two binary values representing black or white.

Comment: I have a color image that I have used to create a histogram. Based on my math up there I am able to get various shades of red, green, and blue and their intensity value. I would like to do the same for black, (0, 0, 0), and white (255, 255, 255) color values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two methods:

1. Create `whiteCount` and `blackCount` variables. Iterate through all the pixels and increment `whiteCount` if the pixel is (255, 255, 255) and increment `blackCount` if the pixel is (0, 0, 0).
2. Convert the image to grayscale, create a histogram and look at the first and last bins.

Comment: The second method seems to be the best method possible. Thanks